# Why is keeping entities in memory after session closed considered bad practice in Nhibernate?

Tags: c#, session, nhibernate

I have a website that inserts data into NH entities,

the server keeps the entity in memory,
while inserting/changing data on the site the server updates only the relevant information and at save time it just saves the entity it has in memory.

This was done because of the complexity of the entities.

I read that it is a bad practice to keep entities in memory after the session is closed,
I make sure there is no lazy loading, and when a new session is created to save the entity - it works fine.

We can't use 2nd level caching as we change the entities a lot without saving, only when the user decides he wants to save we save the in memory entity, or rollback the changes if needed.

What issues can arise from using it like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One important consideration is the longer an object is kept in memory, the greater risk that someone else will change it in the database. How great the risk is depends on your use case.

Comment: Exactly, this consideration is relevant! Because keeping objects out of the session is simply **NOT wrong** by default. We are doing almost the same if we do pass objects *(serialized)* to a client, and get them back *(deserialize)* and call `session.Updated()` or `session.Merge()`. Other words - keeping session outside of the session scope would hardly be considered as a bad. Even cache is kind of doing it. But there are other things to consider. E.g. above Oskars's one...